# Can titles be made more select-friendly?

Tags: feature-request

I am unable to partially select text in titles.

For example, if I want to select `processing a sorted array` part of the following title, I must start from the left or the right, I cannot partially select it because it's a link.

[image: Sample select]

I see two possible solutions:

1. Solve with JavaScript: if a person clicks somewhere on the title and moves the mouse, select that text
2. Don't make titles links: do title of posts need to link to themselves? What is the logic in that?

Comment: *Don't make titles links: do title of posts need to link to themselves? What is the logic in that?* I often (several dozen times a day) use that feature to refresh a question. I know `F5` would work too but I usually have my hand on the mouse at that time, so it find it pretty convenient (the title is a far bigger target than my browser's Refresh button).

Comment: I copy the URL off the title frequently, I suspect many other SO users do as well.  Selecting is a bit clumsy but can be done easy enough, click outside of the link area and drag.

Comment: @HansPassant I use it exactly for that, I often prefer it over the 'share' link, e.g. for internal documentation or a code comment.

Comment: You can press the `F7` key to enable a caret that you can move with your arrows.
With `shift` key you can select what you want.

Comment: On MSE: [Can't select text within the question title](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/248065/289905).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming Windows, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while selecting text that are also links, it's a standard browser feature. See [How to Select Hyperlink Text in Google Chrome?](//superuser.com/q/173200):

> Pressing ALT while selecting text prevents hyperlinks being followed, and therefore allows all or partial text in links to be selected and copied.

This applies, at least, to both Firefox and Chrome.

- On Macs, use the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key.
- On Linux, use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

I never use the title for anything other than reading and editing but this doesn't seem to be too hard. Let me demonstrate with a drawring

[image]

Comment: I love that you captured the first line "I am unable to partially select text in title." with your counter-example.

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox on Mac, not with the current site design at any rate. You start dragging the whole title text (it's a link 'object') when you do this, you don't start a select.

Comment: I'm currently only on a 1366x768 screen but here this method needs to be pixel perfect. One pixel above you click the link and one pixel below the text is selected from the right side. It might be better on a bigger screen. Edit: Okay, it's actually 2 pixels, but still...

Comment: @syntonym the other answer from Martijn is probably better. But this is 3 years old and seems to work in many situations

Comment: Indeed, it can just about work in the right location, but it's very finicky.

Comment: Starting above the text increases the "hitbox" to 5 pixel for me. Sorry I missed that this is already 3 years old.

Comment: I have Google Chrome and it works when I start above the text instead of below it.