# Hard to select text in question title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Since the re-design the question title is now a clickable link and it's almost impossible to select text in the middle of the title. If I click outside the title text I can swipe and select all of the text but clicking in the middle of the string on seems to start a drag event.

Is this by design? How can I select a single word in the middle of the question title?

Comment: Re question title being a link - It's something that I don't understand.  What's the point of having a page title that links to itself?  When would anyone ever want or need to click that?

Comment: @billynoah: link selection (right-click to select link), quick opening a new tab to compare answers (middle-click the link), etc.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes more sense

Comment: “Since the re-design”? The title has always been a link. I’ve seen a similar question before, with an answer that suggests starting the selection of the text up to a few pixels below or above the link.

Comment: There we go, found it: [Can Titles be made more select-friendly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306193/4642212), and [Can't select text within the question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248065/289905).

Comment: Ah I guess the issue has been around for awhile. The title makes no visible affordance that it is a clickable link. So today when I tried to select some text in the middle of the title I was surprised when I was unable.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this would be by design.

Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while selecting text that are also links, it's a standard browser feature. See [How to Select Hyperlink Text in Google Chrome?](//superuser.com/q/173200):

> Pressing ALT while selecting text prevents hyperlinks being followed, and therefore allows all or partial text in links to be selected and copied.

On Macs, that's the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely a usable workaround. Still not my expected behavior when I see what looks like plain text at the top of a question.

Comment: Do you have a solution for touch screen devices like Apple or Android tablets?

Comment: @alexolut: that's tricker, granted. I usually end up hitting the 'edit' button and then copying the contents of the 'title' box before cancelling the edit.